# Handling incremental data - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, architecture, hive, hbase, hadoop2

We had 5 years of data in cluster and we are loading the data everyday. The data that gets added everyday might contain duplicate data , partially modified data etc ..

1 . How to handle duplicate data - should that be handled as part of highlevel programming interfaces pig, hive etc .. or any other alternatives.

2. Say if there is a usecase to find out what is changed between two records given the key to find out the row.

What is the best way to model the data, using which hadoop eco system components.

Answer (score 0):

> How to handle duplicate data

It's very hard to remove duplicates from HDFS raw data,
so I guess your approach is right: remove using `pig` or `hive` while loading those data.

> Say if there is a usecase to find out what is changed between two records given the key to find out the row.

For this case, do you meaning that two records has the same key?

Then what kind of changes you want to capture?

Comment: thanks for quick reply. We wanted to capture if there is a field associated with the record is changed and inform the stakeholders about this change

Answer (score 0):

When you say that, you need to remove duplicates and also the delta between two records when you know the key, you should have some criteria of which data to be removed in case of partial changed data.

In both scenarios, you can have a handle of the key and write logic to remove duplicates. **Map reduce** seems to be a good choice, given the parallelism, performance and ability to manage based on keys. Mostly your requirements could be handled in reducer

Comment: thanks for quick reply. do you mean the map reduce job should be invoked for everytime the data is loaded and process it before store in hdfs

Comment: Well map reduce works on data which is in hdfs. More general way is sqoop it into hdfs from existing database and then use map reduce to perform analysis on it. I am not sure what is the source for your data

Comment: i mean, mapreduce process data from hdfs and then store it in hdfs after processing( removing duplicates). I was looking for any high level abstractions that will shorten the development time and thereby reduces time.

Comment: What is type of data? Structured-Unstructured or semi-structured? What is  source of data - File Or database ? If you want abstractions, it depends on  type of data to work with best tools.

Comment: it is in xml format and source of data is file based.

Comment: Ok since your data source is in the form of xml files, you cannot use sqoop. Best choice could be using Hive with an xml serde. Managing duplicate data and general process wrt Hive is guve [here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/) and how you deal with xmls with Hive is give [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031663/hive-xml-serde-table-is-empty). Partial data duplicates verification could be difficult with them. And you can always write distinct and other conditions in HQL and load that data into another table.

Answer (score 0):

See if `Sqoop-merge` fits your use case.

From the doc:
The merge tool allows you to combine two datasets where entries in one dataset should overwrite entries of an older dataset. For example, an incremental import run in last-modified mode will generate multiple datasets in HDFS where successively newer data appears in each dataset. The merge tool will "flatten" two datasets into one, taking the newest available records for each primary key.

Comment: the datasource is xml files , can sqoop handle that

Comment: @srihay sqoop merge takes a primary id of the dataset and overwrites the new value onto the old one. Now, that value can be anything (XML, JSON, text etc.)