# move xml data from hive table field to another hive table created a row format serde

Tags: hive

need you help to know a solution about xml data in hive.

1) below hive table "books_xml" contains only one field named "xmldata" in which I have saved xml data as a single string.

```
hive> select xmldata from books_xml;
OK
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog><book>  <id>11</id> 
<genre>Computer</genre>  <price>44</price></book><book>  <id>44</id> 
<genre>Fantasy</genre>  <price>5</price></book></catalog>
Time taken: 0.175 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

2) I want to export above xml data (which is in field) into below hive table created with SERDE properties?

```
CREATE TABLE books_serde (
   id STRING, 
   genre STRING, 
   price DOUBLE
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.id"="/book/id/text()",
"column.xpath.genre"="/book/genre/text()",
"column.xpath.price"="/book/price/text()"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<book>",
"xmlinput.end"="</book>"
);
```

Comment: this can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031663/hive-xml-serde-table-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

Create the 2nd table as external table with pointing to the `LOCATION` of the first table,

```
LOCATION /user/hive/warehouse/dbname/books_xml
```

This may solve you problem.